# Preserve list ordering when creating maps in Terraform 0.12?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I have the following snippets in my configuration - the idea is to change current logic/syntax from 0.11 to 0.12. First, I am creating a map from lists,

```
my_vars = zipmap(
  var.foo_vars,
  flatten(data.terraform_remote_state.foo.*.outputs.some_id)
)
```

Then iterate over it to produce some key value pairs.

```
...
"var": [for key in keys(local.my_vars) :
  {
    name  = key
    value = lookup(local.my_vars, key)
  }
],
...
```

And here is the relevant tfvars configuration.

```
foo_vars = [
    "A",
    "B",
    "C"
]
```

The problem is that this logic doesn't seem to preserver order and I can't figure out a good way to make this happen. From what I understand, once you turn the lists into a map with `zipmap`, the order is recalculated. Is there anything that can be done to have the original order preserved?

I'm not tied to the current solution, so maybe there is a way to generate the key/values that doesn't require a map to be created first and can be done instead with only the two lists?

```
~ foo          = [
                        {
                            name  = "A"
                            value = "1"
                        },
                      - {
                          - name  = "B"
                          - value = "2"
                        },
                        {
                            name  = "C"
                            value = "3"
                        },
                      + {
                          + name      = "B"
                          + valueFrom = "2"
                        },
                    ]
```

Comment: i could be incorrect, but I believe iterating in that syntax will implicitly convert the `list` type to the unordered `set` type, and thus lose the ordering regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing here is that, as you've noticed, Terraform's map type is an unordered map which identifies elements only by their keys, not by permission. Therefore if you have a situation where you need to preserve the order of a sequence then a map is not a suitable data structure to use.

I have a suspicion that keeping things ordered may not actually be necessary to solve your underlying problem here, but I can't tell from the information you've shared what the real-world meaning of all of these values is, so I'm going to answer on the assumption that you *do* need to preserve the order. If you are working with ordered sequences only because you are creating multiple instances of a resource using `count`, I'd suggest that you consider using [resource `for_each`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#for_each-multiple-resource-instances-defined-by-a-map-or-set-of-strings) instead, which may allow you to solve your underlying problem in a way that is not sensitive to the order of items in `var.foo_vars`.

---

Given two lists of the same length, you can produce a new list that combines the corresponding elements from each list by writing a [`for` expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions) like this:

```
locals {
  my_vars = [
    for i, some_id in data.terraform_remote_state.foo.*.outputs.some_id : {
      name  = var.foo_vars[i]
      value = some_id
    }
  ]
}
```

The above relies on the fact that `i` index values from one list are correlated with the element of the same index in the other list, and so we can use the `i` from the data source instances to access the corresponding element of `var.foo_vars`.